# Who should be set to authorizing_account when creating an account?

Tags: accounts

Who should be set to authorizing_account when creating an account using **'cleos system newaccount**' on the main net?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The authorizing account should normally be an account you own and have control over it. Think of it as a "parent" of the new account. It can be used to split your account to several different accounts each one with its own funds and dapp.

Answer (score 0):

Any existing account can create a new account. Once created, the new account is not owned by or controlled by the existing one. If you need one account to control another, use `cleos set account permission` after creation.